# Twilio client browser issue - Warning: 13227 - Dial: No International Authorization

Tags: twilio

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client/incoming-calls <-- I've gone through the tutorial on this page, copied/pasted everything and when I run a test the call goes through and hangs up right away, never ringing my browser. Here is some info (including error):

C# MVC application
Phone Number I'm calling is a toll free number
Changed jenny to wayne (as my name is wayne)
Get Warning in app logs:

Warning: 13227 - Dial: No International Authorization

Not really sure why I'm getting the No International Authorization, I'm making a call from my personal Cell phone to the toll free number, and my c# code in the application to handle the call is as follows:

```
public ActionResult SendCallToWayne()
{
  var response = new TwilioResponse();
  response.Dial("wayne", new { callerId = "Toll Free Number" });
  return new TwiMLResult(response);
}
```

I recently added the callId value, but it didn't make a difference. the resulting XML looks the same as the example in the Link provided above.

I've search StackOverFlow, as well as google, and have not found a solution to my problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Wayne

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to use DialClients, not Dial. Error could have been a bit better, but since it translated wayne to 92963 I suppose it's the correct error to be returned.

Wayne